# Download a Document with Autodesk API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to download documents from BIM 360 Docs. If I want to download a file with the type `"type": "items:autodesk.bim360:File"` I just need to get the bucketID and objectID (`/projects/<projectID>/items/<itemID>`) and call `buckets/<bucketID>/objects/<ObjectID>`. (I used [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/documen-management/download-document/) tutorial)

But how do I download a file with the type `"type": "items:autodesk.bim360:Document"`?

First, I get the version of the document `/projects/<projectID>/items/<itemID>/versions`. After that I call `projects/<ProjectID>/versions/<versionID>/downloadFormats` but it returns an empty JSON. The call `projects/<ProjectID>/versions/<versionID>/downloads` returns a 400 Bad Input. Whats the right way to get the bucket & objectID from a "document"? The way from the tutorial doesn't work because there is no "storage" tag in the JSON ([example](https://prnt.sc/mtyemk)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For BIM 360 Project Folder items, follow the tutorial [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/documen-management/download-document/) to download document.

Basically you will need to obtain the URN of the document from the `relationships.storage.data.id` field via `GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents`.

For item type items:autodesk.bim360:Document, call `GET projects/:project_id/versions/:version_id/relationships/refs` to obtain the storage locations:

```
 "storage": {
          "meta": {
            "link": {
              "href": "/oss/v2/buckets/wipbucket/objects/urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod%2F9f8bdc3f-e29c-4ada-ab7b-bb8dfa821163.pdf"
            }
          }
```

See doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-refs-GET/).

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that before but if the filetype is a "document" there is no "storage" tag in the JSON which includes the objectID. There is an example: http://prnt.sc/mtyemk

Comment: sorry didnt realize you were trying to get Doc items. see edit

Comment: FYI. for item type `items:autodesk.bim360:Document` , you can obtain its file storage locations via calling `GET projects/:project_id/versions/:version_id/relationships/refs` with my experience.

Comment: Thanks! Just added that to the answer