# API Download File from BIM360 Doc Plans folder

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to download file from Autodesk BIM360 Doc (https://docs.b360.autodesk.com) with the Forge API so the files can be then afterward archieved to our local storage.

I have managed to download any files from **"Project Files"** folder using the data management API https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-GET/, with which i can get the storage id under **data.relationships.storage.data.id**.

however with the same API i cannot get the storage Id when querying files under **"Plan"** folder,

So is there any way with Forge API we can download a file from Plan folder? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item listed in the Plan folder is a type of `items:autodesk.bim360:Document`, this type item won't have storage attribute shown in its responses of [GET versions/:version_id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-GET/) and [GET items/:item_id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/) directly.

To obtain the physical file location, you should call [GET versions/:version_id/relationships/refs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-relationships-refs-GET/) instead, see here for the similar thread: [Download a Document with Autodesk API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978434/download-a-document-with-autodesk-api)

**Update for copied item**

While accessing the relationship data of version of the copied item via [GET versions/:version_id/relationships/refs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-relationships-refs-GET/), you would see a data attribute telling the relationship between the copied item and the source item with my experience:

```
"data": [
    {
        "type": "versions",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.34Xvlw1jTcSQ_XkIVh07cg?version=2",
        "meta": {
            "refType": "derived",
            "fromId": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.34Xvlw1jTcSQ_XkIVh07cg?version=2",
            "fromType": "versions",
            "toId": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.y3L7YbfAQJWwumMgqjJUxg?version=1",
            "toType": "versions",
            "direction": "to",
            "extension": {
                "type": "derived:autodesk.bim360:CopyDocument",
                "version": "1.0",
                "schema": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/derived:autodesk.bim360:CopyDocument-1.0"
                },
                "data": {}
            }
        }
    }
],
```

Afterward, you have to access the version relationship dat of the `fromId` via calling [GET versions/:version_id/relationships/refs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-relationships-refs-GET/).

In this case, it's `{PROJ_ID}/versions/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.34Xvlw1jTcSQ_XkIVh07cg%3Fversion=2/relationships/refs`, then you will see the `storage` attribute inside the response with my investigation.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer, API  GET versions/:version_id/relationships/refs already tried, however no lucky. the type of the item is **derived:autodesk.bim360:CopyDocument**, and there's no storage node returned

Comment: Could you share more details about the `derived:autodesk.bim360:CopyDocument`? It seems that I haven't seen this before. How did you create this type of item?

Comment: When a document is moved or copied to a different folder under Plan library, w get a different item type, eg. **derived:autodesk.bim360:CopyDocument** or **derived:autodesk.bim360:FileToDocument**, in our case we used the approval workflow of the BIM360 Docs to copy approved files into an stage folder, and thus what we get data.meta.extension.type which equals **derived:autodesk.bim360:CopyDocument**

Comment: I have updated the answer, please have a try. It works from my side as expected. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, this solves most of the case.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else run into the same issue, i post my code with which i finally managed to get the file storage information. However please feel free to suggest other approaches than iteration to the full relationship trees.

```
internal static ForgeFileInfo getItemVersion(string token, string projectID, string versionID)
    {
        ForgeFileInfo forgeFileInfo = new ForgeFileInfo();

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        versionApi.Configuration.AccessToken = token;
        var version = versionApi.GetVersion(projectID, versionID);
        string fileType = version.data.attributes.extension.type;
        switch (fileType) {
            case "versions:autodesk.bim360:File":
                //File from Project File library or is regual file
                forgeFileInfo.FileName = version.data.attributes.displayName;
                forgeFileInfo.FileLocation = version.data.relationships.storage.meta.link.href;
                forgeFileInfo.StorageId = version.data.relationships.storage.data.id;
                return forgeFileInfo;
            case "versions:autodesk.bim360:Document":
                //File from Plan Library
                var versionRelationship=versionApi.GetVersionRelationshipsRefs(projectID, versionID);

                // the GET Relationship has data node where we can get the related document
                var relationshipData = new DynamicDictionaryItems(versionRelationship.data);
                // let's start iterating the relationship DATA
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> relationshipItem in relationshipData)
                {
                    //Have to loop until we found "derived:autodesk.bim360:FileToDocument"
                    var relationType = relationshipItem.Value.meta.extension.type;
                    var relation = relationshipItem.Value.meta.direction;
                    if ("derived:autodesk.bim360:FileToDocument".Equals(relationType))
                    {
                        if ("to".Equals(relation))
                        {
                            //Go up stream
                            return getItemVersion(token, projectID, relationshipItem.Value.id);
                        }
                    }
                    else if ("derived:autodesk.bim360:CopyDocument".Equals(relationType))
                    {
                        if ("to".Equals(relation))
                        {
                            //Go up stream
                            return getItemVersion(token, projectID, relationshipItem.Value.id);
                        }
                        continue;
                    }               
                }
                break;
        }
        return forgeFileInfo;
    }
```