# Autodesk Forge: How to find URL of svf-file of a model in BIM 360 Docs

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Where can I find the URL of a svf-file of a model in BIM 360 Docs?
The feature loadModel for the Viewer3D in Autodesk Forge requires this URL as described here:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loadmodel-url-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55338576/7745569

The derivative urn will be found that aside from the storage attribute in the relationships attribute, like the below:

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },

    // ...

    "data": [
        {
            "type": "versions",

            // ...

            "relationships": {

                // ...

                "derivatives": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "derivatives",
                        "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLmlMR2hBMURUUVJPVWxTV3JuMFJzekE_dmVyc2lvbj0x"
                    },

                    // ...

                },

                // ...

                "storage": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "objects",
                        "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/47780ef7-6ebe-4028-a7af-7d3e8016ff7e.ifc"
                    },

                    // ...

                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```