# How to open on a specific page a PDF File on Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I need to open a PDF file from BIM 360 Docs on the Viewer selecting a specific page. I'm currently opening the PDF on the Viewer but I don't know how to select a page.

Comment: In the default viewer every pdf page is accessable as a viewable within a translated document. If you list all viewables you can switch between pages, get a well placed extension with `-` and  `+` and you got a pretty well emulated pdf viewer. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Samuel. I'm new to Forge. How can initialize the Viewer using a specific page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on to my comment, you can get a list of all available viewables when using the `onDocumentLoadSucces` callback. This callback is triggered after initting the viewer and loading the first Urn(model) into the viewer. You can look into more functionality on bubble nodes in the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/BubbleNode/)

Example in angular/typescript:

```
private onDocumentLoadSucces(viewerDocument: Autodesk.Viewing.Document) {
    // Default viewable
    let defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    // list of all viewables in this model
    this.viewables = viewerDocument.getRoot().search({'type':'geometry'});
    // We load in the default viewable here but we could choose to load any viewable
    // in this.viewables
    this.viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
    console.log('model changed');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel. It can helps me to understand how to access the views.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the PDF extension to directly load and view PDF. If so, you can tell it the page number in the loadModel call. For example:

```
viewer.loadModel( pdf, {page:2});
```

Here's the whole function:

```
function initializeViewer( pdf ) {
   var options = {
        env: "Local",
        useADP: false
   }
   Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
      viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('viewer3D'));
      viewer.setTheme("light-theme");
      viewer.start();
      if (!pdf) return;
      viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.PDF').then( () => {
            viewer.loadModel( pdf, {page:2});
      });
    });
};
```

The docs mention this here:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/PDFExtension/
and there is also an example I used to test from a blog post here:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/fast-pdf-viewingmarkup-inside-forge-viewer

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks kevinvandecar for the quick answer.I'm not using the PDF Extension to load it on the Viewer. The way I am accessing the PDF is through BIM 360Docs, looking for the 'derivative' field to launch the viewer. What is the best way to view a PDF stored in BIM 360 Docs (in both cases: Plans folder and Project Files)?

Comment: Please check here for finding storage or derivative fields: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55338576/7745569

Comment: FYI, I double checked internally and sounds like BIM 360 PDF viewing is not supported in the Viewer PDF extension. As others here have said, you will have to use the translated viewables. For a specific page you will need to select the viewable for that PDF page. Sorry for any misinformation earlier and thanks for @Samuel Middendorp detailed response.

Comment: Thanks for making that clarification