# Download Source File equivalent in Forge API for Plan

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

The blog post https://blogs.autodesk.com/anztechteam/2019/09/21/downloading-the-bim360-design-files-from-bim360-docs/ describes how the UI includes linked files as a zip (command "Download source files") for a Revit in the Plans folder. Is there an equivalent on the Forge Document Management APIs for this, or any other easy way to "collect" all the linked files? (maybe similar as outlined in [API Download File from BIM360 Doc Plans folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338303/api-download-file-from-bim360-doc-plans-folder))

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible, we don't have a batch download API.
What you can do is, download all the required files parallelly, zip it, and then send it to the user.

Comment: There not being a ready-made API is fine with me. However, is there a sample maybe that shows how to collect all the linked files & then download those? (eg how do I tell that a file is a linked file)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, we don't have a sample for that.